# Strange PDO select statement behaviour - selecting only first record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**EDIT: my bad it was a typo in db - all records had an extra whitespace at the beginning of code, apart from the first one - that's why I was getting only the first record**

Its the simplest query - I find record with the corresponding `code` and `active` field with value 1. If there is such record I update its `active` field to 0.

```
    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE code=? AND active=1";
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);  
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $result = $STH->execute(array($_POST["code"]));
    $row = $STH->fetchAll();

    echo "<pre>", var_dump($row), "</pre>";
    echo $result , " rows: " . $STH->rowCount();

    if($STH->rowCount() == 0){
      echo "Error - this code is inactive";
    }else{
      echo "Code succesfully activated";
      $STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE codes SET active=0 WHERE code=?"); 
      $STH->execute(array($_POST["code"]));
    }
```

But it only works for the first record `847BKX`. If I try to search for others it always returns 0 rows even though the `active` field is still 1.
Here is the snapshot from DB - `code` field is indexed `varchar` length 255. How come it only works for the first record and not others...?

[image]

Comment: Are you getting a valid value in `$_POST["code"]`?

Comment: Yes - I even tried with hardcoded values.. and still the same.. so weird..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the error is caused by typo

Answer (score 0):

how i see its not working for any of the field because your update statement says to update the active to 0 if found. I am not sure if you are getting anything from

```
array($_POST["code"]);
```

if its just one input field then just use

```
$_POST["code"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop if you want to have multiple values in placeholders

```
foreach($_POST["code"] as $Row){

        $STH->execute($Row) 

}
```